# Cannot use import statement outside a module in .spec.ts files NodeJs

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js, chai

For unit testing, I use mocha + chai.
I run the command with `"test": "mocha --require ts-node/register 'src/**/*spec.ts'"`.

When I use import in *spec.ts files (for example `import { expect } from 'chai';`)

I get error `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["dom", "es2018"],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "strict": true,
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `const expect = require('chai')`?

This is a way to wrap modules used in [CommonJS](https://medium.com/@cgcrutch18/commonjs-what-why-and-how-64ed9f31aa46) which is equivalent to `import { expect } from 'chai';`.

Comment: This work, but I want to import modules with that style. Maybe I miss something? Because other ts files are worked perfectly, but not .spec.ts files.

Answer (score -2):

"mocha" is only designed for **commonJS** modules. You can find it by searching for the README file in node_modules/mocha.

If you want to use **esnext**, I recommend you "jest" instead. It doesn't vary that much from "mocha".

An example of configuration that works for me:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ]
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "website",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "test": "jest",
    "test-watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "pretty": "prettier --write \"**/*.js\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.9",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "next": "9.3.4",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^25.2.1",
    "@types/node": "^13.11.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.32",
    "jest": "^25.2.7",
    "prettier": "^2.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "^25.3.1",
    "ts-node": "^8.8.1",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  }
}
```

**jest.config.json**

```
module.exports = {
  roots: ["<rootDir>"],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
  },
  testRegex: "(/tests/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.tsx?$",
  moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "json", "node"]
};
```

Comment: Jest is terrible, it's slow, do not use it.  Just stick with mocha.

Comment: She's asking about mocha specifically